# ConvertEmptyStringsToNull not present in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I have just migrated to Laravel Framework 5.3 to 5.4.11.

Now, I'm looking for the Middleware : ConvertEmptyStringsToNull

it should be in :

> \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\

But inside this folder, I can only find:

```
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyPostSize::class,
```

I have no ConvertEmptyStringsToNull Middleware in  vendor/

What should I do???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you may extend the original middleare (`ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php`) class from `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware` directory and put the extended class into the `App\Http\Middleware` directory, for example, just create the following class as it's given below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull as BaseConvertEmptyStringsToNull;

class ConvertEmptyStringsToNull extends BaseConvertEmptyStringsToNull
{

    // ...

}
```

Now, you can use it as a global middleware. To use it globally, you need to add this middleware class (if not there already) in the `$middleware` property of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` class, for example:

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

Comment: it would be great, but Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull doesn't exists... Or I'm not understanding you.  I don't have an original Middleware of this one :(